# Dataset attribute as a function parameter

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, typescript

Is it possible to use the dataset attribute as a function parameter?
I want that when I click the button to start the editCategory function and pass it as an id parameter from the data-id.
Thanks.

```
function printCategory(category: CategoryType){
        return(
            <tr>
                <td>{category.categoryId}</td>
                <td>{category.name}</td>
                <th><Button variant="secondary" size="sm" data-id={category.categoryId} onClick={()=>editCategory()}>Edit</Button></th>
            </tr>
        )
    }
```

Comment: What is `Button`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

##### The easier approach:

```
onClick={e => editCategory(e.target.getAttribute('data-id'))}
```

##### The `useRef` approach:

```
const editButtonRef = React.useRef()
```

and then in the button's markup:

```
onClick={() => editCategory(editButtonRef.getAttribute('data-id'))}
```

*Note that this approach might consume more memory, use as a last resort.*